# Como esconder uma div com timeout no AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, timeout

Sou novata no AngularJS e estou apanhando para resolver problemas simples.

Tenho o meu controller

```
mainAppControllers.controller('NomeCtrl', ['myservice','$rootScope','$scope', '$routeParams', '$location','$timeout',
    function(myservice,$rootScope , $scope, $routeParams, $location,$timeout){
```

e meu html

```
<div id="loaderViwew">
        <a id="btnInfo" ng-click="btnInfo()"><img src="img/btninfo.png" /></a>  
        <a id="close" ng-click="btnFechar()"><img src="img/closeMenu.png" /> </a> 
        <img id="alertScanIcon" src="img/iconeScanAlert.png" />
</div>
```

Como faço para esconder a div com um timeout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

Adicione a diretiva `ngHide` na sua `div`.

```
<div id="loaderViwew" ng-hide="hideLoader">
        .....
</div>
```

No seu controller você adiciona a variável `hideLoader` inicialmente com valor `false` e coloca o `$timeout` para trocar o valor para `true`, o que vai fazer com que a diretiva `ngHide` esconda o elemento.

```
$scope.hideLoader = false;

$timeout(function(){
    $scope.hideLoader = true;
}, 3000);
```

Se você pretende reusar esta view em outras áreas eu sugiro que você crie uma [diretiva](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) para gerenciar isso ao invés de usar este método acima.

Comment: Obrigado @André Ribeiro dei super certo!